# I can not install OpenMDAO

Tags: anaconda3, openmdao

I have installed Anaconda since it was recommended to use in the OpenMDAO's website. After that I typed `pip install 'openmdao[all]'` as instructed. However I get an error message saying, "ERROR: Invalid requirement: "'openmdao[all]'"" I was wondering how can I solve this issue. I have no knowledge about the Python or anaconda therefore I don't have a clue what to do about this situation. I searched the internet however I didn't find a solution to this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you're running the wrong pip executable. Try `which pip` - it should be located under your home directory instead of a system path such as `/bin/pip` or `/usr/bin/pip`.

Make sure you've created and activated an environment in Anaconda:

```
conda create -n myenv pip
conda activate myenv
python -m pip install 'openmdao[all]'
```

That command sequence will give the highest chance of success. The single quotes are required for shells like zsh.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes:

```sh
pip install openmdao[all]
```